# Ошибка NotSupportedException в EntityFramework при попытке выполнить запрос

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Когда пытаюсь выполнить следующий запрос
`var del = context.Documents.Remove((context.Documents.Where(doc => doc.DocumentID == ((int)dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value)).FirstOrDefault()));`

Вылетает ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.NotSupportedException" в
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell get_Item(Int32)' method,
>   and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите `(int)dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value` в переменную

Ошибка возникает потому что EF не может преобразовать это выражение в SQL запрос.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Пока ждал ответа, получилось еще сделать так вот
`var del = context.Documents.Remove(context.Documents.AsEnumerable().Select(doc => doc).Where(doc => doc.DocumentID == ((int)dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value)).FirstOrDefault());`

Comment: @PyrejkeeПурешкин это вы глупость сделали. Почитайте что делает `AsEnumerable`...